# How to combine sed 'sentences'?

Tags: linux, sed

I made this script:

```
xrandr | grep '*' | sed 's/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g'| sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/x.*//'
```

How can I combine the three `sed` commands:

1. `sed 's/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g'`
2. `sed 's/ //g'`
3. `sed 's/x.*//'`

into a single command?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm running sed three to do this job. My question is: how to use only one sed to do the same thing.

Comment: You have (at least) 4 different answers, each of them accurate and each providing an alternative way to do the same job.  Let no-one say your choices are limited.  The answer by William Pursell should probably 'win' because he points out that the `grep` is unnecessary.

Comment: No need N `sed` at all, I use only 1 `grep` (or 1 `perl`) =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-e`:

```
xrandr | grep '*' | sed -e 's/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g' -e 's/ //g' -e 's/x.*//'
```

Note that the `grep` is not necessary:

```
xrandr | sed -e '/\*/!d' -e 's/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g' -e 's/ //g' -e 's/x.*//'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put those commands in a file called sedscr for example, one per line as such:

```
s/x.*//
s/ //g
s/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g
```

And then call:

```
xrandr | grep '*' | sed -f sedscr
```

I prefer this method, just in case I want to add more commands in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply consider all `sed` commands as script and add a `;` between commands :

```
xrandr | grep '*' | sed 's/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g ; s/ //g ; s/x.*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

With *newlines* :

```
echo coobas | sed 's:c:f:
s:s:r:'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `sed` but just `grep` :

```
$ xrandr | grep -oP '^\s+\K\d+(?=.*?\*)'
1440
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ xrandr | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^\s+(\d+)(?=.*?\*)/'
1440
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is to make a sed config file (call it **config.sed**) listing all replacement rules.  E.g.:

```
1,/^END/{
   s/x.*//
   s/ //g
   s/\S*\(*+\)\S*//g
}
```

and then run

```
sed -f config.sed filein.txt > fileout.txt
```